# Modify Kubernetes Deployment revision history limit

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

How would we modify the default history limit in kubernetes. At this point, the default history limit is 3 revisions. I would like to increase this by 10.

I use the below command to get the revision history

`kubectl rollout history deployment <deployment name>`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, I found the answer to this.

Every Deployment has its own revision limit stored in its replica set in this field `.spec.revisionHistoryLimit`. The respective replica set needs to be updated in order to change the revision limit.